# "Your account is temporarily unavailable. Regain access by logging in from a web browser"

Tags: facebook, login, user-accounts, hacked

A friend of mine has asked for help because his Hotmail account, and Facebook account associated with it, have been hacked. There's no way to recover the Hotmail account - the hacker has secured it with alternative 'phone number and email address. However, my friend only wants his Facebook back as he doesn't use Hotmail.

My friend knows his Facebook email and his old password, from before the hacker changed it, and knows all of his friends.

- I enter his email address and old password. Facebook says: It's an old password, do you want to change it? *Yes*.
- Send an email to your Hotmail or sign in with your Hotmail?: *No longer have access to these*.
- Facebook says: Enter a new email where we can reach you: *I enter an email address*.
- Facebook will send codes to three of your friends in order to recover your Facebook account. *Okay, great, continue*.
- Now I see `Your account is temporarily unavailable. Regain access by logging in from a web browser.`

Comment: @pnuts yes, he changed hotmail password, if you click reset password, it says send text message to somenumber or call somenumber or email the hacker

Comment: @pnuts my question is when or how to stop seeing that error and instead just go forward with the process of asking friends to reset the password

Comment: @pnuts, yes im talking about the error logging to fb from web browser

Comment: If anyone has a solution, I will give him 50 rep bounty as soon as I'm allowed to open a bounty, if the solution solves the issue of course

Comment: Did you try logging in from a web browser?

Comment: @Yuliy yes I'm always on pc, never tried logging in from mobile in the first place